# SpringBoot JPA repositories bean naming strategy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a larger spring boot application where duplicate class names are kinda unavoidable across different domains (thus they are distinguished by packages belonging to these business domains). This ofc leads to duplicate beans which is resolved using `SpringApplicationBuilder.beanNameGenerator` in main method. Works like a charm, naturally.

Where it doesn't work though are integration tests (`@SpringBootTest` & `@DataJpaTest`) which, again, understandable, since these are not using the main method to instantiate the test and it's context.

A simple solution would've been using either `@ComponentScan#nameGenerator` or `@SpringBootApplicaiton#nameGenerator` since the configurations from these annotations are reflected in test configuration. Except for, these name generators are not applied to JPA repositories (or their resulting beans if you wish). The name generators are applied though, since apart from conflicting JPA repository names I have also a couple conflicting REST controller names and when using the annotation configuration approach, instead of failing the startup at these, it fails at JPA repositories.

My question is, am I looking at a desired behavior and are JPA repositories treated differently as far as naming is concerned? Or is it some kind of misbehavior and should I file an issue? I haven't found anything regarding this matter but it seems kinda unlikely it hasn't been found out yet.